# Garbage getting added to when reading from a file in android

Tags: android, file, inputstream

I have a file 'diagnosis.txt' in assets folder of the project containing a long json string, when i try to get that string it appends garbage at the start of the string and add '\' in the middles of the json. Can anyone tell how to remove this garbage text?

Garbage:

> {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1343\cocoasubrtf140
>   {\fonttbl\f0\fmodern\fcharset0 Courier;}
>   {\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;\red0\green0\blue0;}
>   \margl1440\margr1440\vieww10800\viewh8400\viewkind0
>   \deftab720
>   \pard\pardeftab720
>   \f0\fs24 \cf2 \expnd0\expndtw0\kerning0
>   \outl0\strokewidth0 \strokec2 [{"code":"A000","description":"Cholera due to Vibrio cholerae 01, biovar cholerae"},{"code":"A001","description":"Cholera due to Vibrio cholerae 01, biovar eltor"},{"code":"A009","description":"Cholera, unspecified"},{"code":"A0100","description":"Typhoid fever, unspecified"}]}

```
public static String loadJSONFromAsset(Context context) throws IOException {

    String json = null;
    try {

        InputStream is = context.getAssets().open("diagnosis.txt");

        int size = is.available();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];

        is.read(buffer);

        is.close();

        json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");


    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return json;

}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not the file?

Comment: when i open the file in textedit by clicking on it, it shows only the below given text but when i get the content of the file using the above given code, it gives me some weird garbage text.

[{"code":"A000","description":"Cholera due to Vibrio cholerae 01, biovar cholerae"},{"code":"A001","description":"Cholera due to Vibrio cholerae 01, biovar eltor"},{"code":"A009","description":"Cholera, unspecified"},{"code":"A0100","description":"Typhoid fever, unspecified"}]}

Comment: Make sure you're viewing it in plaintext mode: http://www.tekrevue.com/tip/textedit-plain-text-mode/

Comment: That data is in the file itself, you are just not seeing it in your text editor. Use a different text editor, switch to plaintext, clean the file, and your problem will be solved. Your code is working fine.

Comment: Thanks Ken, i changed it to Plain text and it worked !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That data is in the file itself, you are just not seeing it in your text editor.

Use a different text editor, switch to plaintext, clean the file, and your problem will be solved.

**Your code is working fine.**

Here is for example how you can switch or convert to plaintext in TextEdit:
http://www.tekrevue.com/tip/textedit-plain-text-mode/